# How does for loop work inside javascript's eval()?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator, iteration, eval

sorry if I bother someone with this simple question, but I just can not get around all of this concepts in one for loop
and can not understand how this code can be written in a more explicite manner

Code:

```
eval(`for(a=c=100n**n*20n,d=1n;a*=d;)c+=a/=d+++d`)
```

What I have so far:

```
let c=100n**n*20n
for(let a=100n**n*20n, d=1n; a*=d; ) {
    c+=a/=d+++d
}
```

How I understand it: We instantiate 2 variables(a and d) insider the for loop and incrementing a at each iteration with a = a * d.
Question: How do I read the c variable update `c+=a/=d+++d` and until what condition this for loop will be executed ?

Thanks for any expiation on the topic!
PS: it does not matter if your explanation will be using BigInts as in this example

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). What do you mean by _“How do I read the c variable update”_? Are you asking what it means? Assignment expressions are evaluated right to left: `c += (a /= (d++ + d))`. See [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/). `a *= d` results in `a * d`. How is `eval` relevant here?

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I dont see a terminal condition for this loop, so can you see at which point will stop executing this loop ?

Comment: The loop stops when `a * d` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).